# How to check what IP wine sees?

Tags: torsocks

I'm using `kalitorify` and on the website it shows changed IP address. What about IP in the game that I'm running on wine? How can I check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `iexplore.exe` which is included in every wineprefix and use some website like `ifconfig.co` that shows your IP. It doesn't guarantee that the game isn't making connections outside the proxy some other way, but at least it shows you that wine is under effect of the routing configuration.